# Android Studio Standalone GCM SDK

Tags: android, blackberry, android-studio, push, google-cloud-messaging

I'm attempting to port my application for Android app that uses push notifications to the Blackberry.  Blackberry has instructions on how to get this working, but I'm stuck at the point where I need to use the Standalone GCM SDK in my project for it to work properly

http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/creating_push-enabled_android_apps.html

I'm doing my Android dev with Android Studio, not Eclipse, does anyone know how to setup my project to use the Standalone GCM SDK?  I'm thinking it has something to do with Gradle but that is where I get lost.

In my build.gradle dependancies I have:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
```

So I'm guessing I have to some how tell the Android Studio compiler to use the standalone Google Cloud Messaging SDK rather the Google Play Services SDK instead?  Where to I get the standalone SDK?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try to install BlackBerry Plug-in for Android Studio here: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/bb_android_studio_plugin_tool.html. You question is more related to the blackberry,  try to ask question here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/bd-p/adt

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I think i may have not clearly stated where my trouble is.  I already have Android Studio installed and working great.  I also already have the BlackBerry plugin installed and working with Android Studio.  The problem I'm having is with configuring Android Studio to use the Standalone Google Cloud Messaging SDK when I compile my project in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio does not support the use of the stand-alone GCM SDK at this time